# What would happen to a particle caught exactly in the middle of two merging black holes both of which are also at the ends of their lives?

Tags: black-holes, event-horizon

If the two tiny, about-to-vanish black holes are of the same mass then such a particle should not go anywhere and remain stationary in the middle even as it gets enveloped inside the new unified event horizon. Now if the singularities were to vanish because of Hawking radiation before they get the time to merge into each other wouldn't that mean that our particle simply pops out of the event horizons as the event horizons split away?

Comment: What about tidal forces?

Comment: I rather suspect  Heisenberg (not Walter)  will take care of this situation